# Debugging Javascript rich front ends with Chrome's developer tools

Tags: javascript, debugging, development-environment

I have a Javascript rich UI that needs some debugging. Everytime I change a function I happen to refresh the page in the browser (F5). What are more efficient ways to see how changes take effect.

To avoid page refresh, I could copy/paste the edited function from the editor to the JS console. Is there any way to make this automatically? Or is there a way to re-read js resources in the developer tools?

Best,
T

Comment: https://www.browsersync.io might interest you.

Comment: Depending on what you have serving your appliction there are auto-reloaders. Other than that tests.

Comment: Browsersync looks awesome, thanks. @Craicerjack, can you point to a specific product?

Comment: @Toni regarding testing there are loads of test suites out there, and for a reloader, once again there are plenty out there but it depends on what you are using to serve your app

Comment: Thanks for your patience. It's a web app that runs on an Apache (wamp) in development. Suggestions?